# Visual Mic Level Display using HTML5/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web, volume

Here's the idea:

A level meter that displays sound output from a user's mic.

The tricky part:

Having it work on a website using only HTML5/Javascript.

Any ideas?

Comment: there is a demo here at https://github.com/cwilso/volume-meter/ which shows the volume response

Comment: This is a clear and and quite explicit question; closing the question seems like a case of moderation system failure (fortunately there are solutions to this elsewhere).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look into the nascent [GetUserMedia API](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html) which you can use to capture a stream from the mic. There's an example [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Live-Web-Audio-Input-Enabled) which should be enough to get you started. Browser support is currently [very limited](http://caniuse.com/#search=GetUserMedia).

The [Web Audio API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html) will allow you to process and visualise the stream but, similarly,  browser support is [very patchy](http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20audio%20api). The example [here](http://www.smartjava.org/content/exploring-html5-web-audio-visualizing-sound) visualises the volume on a signal from a static source, but I imagine it could be adapted to work with a signal captured via the GetUserMedia API.